# Database history changes, same or different table?

Tags: database, performance

I know there are many posts about history tables regarding webstores, but I still have the same question: In case of performance with many (1.000.000+) records, must I store product changes as a new row in the original product table, or do I have to create a separate table with relevant columns to store history versions of a product?

I hope someone can give me a clear advice.

Comment: What db engine you use?

Comment: Sorry didn't see your comment until now. I'm developing using mysql, but migrate to PostgreSql when ready.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build separate history table to avoid too much data and for better performance. You will use separate queries for selecting normal table or record history  - so you can provide different indexes for optimising queries.
You can even store tables in different cluster.

In your main table use stamps like:

- **record_version**
- timestamp
- user (author of change)

optionally also:

- create_date
- update_date
- delete_date (if needed)

Comment: Thanks. The product table is linked to a few other tables, for instance "category", "store (created by)" and "tax". Is it useful to make history tables for all linked tables? Or should I, for example, leave the table "tax" single with and extra column "update_date"?

Comment: You have few options and you should decide what will the best for you. You can add columns to history table for storing additional data like tax or category, you can store foregin key if category or tax row wont change int time (there can be new entriees).

Comment: Think of what is best for your busineess and what data you will need in future.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely use a different table, probably even on a different tablespace on different physical storage: the access characteristics are completely different!

The product table will be queried a lot more than updated, and it's size is relatively stable.

The history table will have much lower load, constant inserts, no updates.